# Probability and Matrices

Tags: combinatorics

A determinant is chosen at random from set of all determinant of matrices having order 2 and entries 0 and 1 only.  the probability that it has zero determinant is.

my ans is  9/16 since total such matrices will be 16 in number and only 9 matrices have determinant zero

where am i wrong how will i calculate how  many such matrices have zero determinant

Comment: The set of determinants here is $\{-1,0,1\}$. Choosing at random from this set gives a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ on a $0$. It is something else to choose a matrix first and then to look at its determinant.

Comment: 1/3 is not an option among correct options since {-1, 0, 1} do not have equally chance of occurence so w cannot apply this method

Comment: You are saying that you choose at random from a *set*. That terminology is practicized if each element of the set has the same probability to be chosen. An element of a set *occurs* only once in it. If you mean something different then you probably must change into: a matrix is chosen randomly from... what is the probability that its determinant equals $0$.

Comment: @Amit If you mean 2 x 2 matrices, I am getting 10/16 by direct count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may be the way to find the matrices..Matrix with one ZERO = 4C1 ,matrix with two 0's is thus 4C2..doing this we obtain 16 cases. The determinants which will have 0 values are obtained from the matrices with

1)two zeroes in the same row or a same column, 2)three zeroes and 3) obviously, if all the elements are zero or one.(though i dont understand the question properly in the sense that whether the matrix can have all same valued entries?)

For the 1st and 2nd case,we have that in 4 ways each.And for the last there can b just 2 ways.
So,the answer to your question is indeed 10/16=5/8

Answer (score 1):

Choosing at random from a set means in this answer that each element
of the set has the same probability to be chosen.

If at random a matrix is chosen having order $2$ and entries $0$
and $1$ then the probability that the matrix has determinant $0$
equals $\frac{10}{16}=\frac{5}{8}$. This because there are $16$
such matrices and $10$ of them have indeed determinant $0$.

If at random an element is chosen from the set that contains exactly
the determinants of matrices described above then the probability
that this element equals $0$ is $\frac{1}{3}$. This because the
set of determinants of these matrices is $\left\{ -1,0,1\right\} $ 
and one of these $3$ elements equals $0$.