# Number of $n\times n$ non-singular $0-1$ matrices

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem**: Find the number of $n\times n$ non-singular matrices where an entry is either $0$ or $1$.

PS: This was motivated by [779412](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779412/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer corresponds to OEIS sequence [A055165](http://oeis.org/A055165). Little seems to be known apart from the forst eight values:
The proportion of singular matrices (among the $2^{n^2}$ candidates) is conjectured to be ${n+1\choose 2}\frac 1{2^{n-1}}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ a finite field with $q$ elements. Let $G=\{g=(a_{ij})_{i,j \le n}  \ ; a_{ij} \in \mathbb{F}_q, \det g \neq 0 \} $. So, we have

$$|G|=q^{n(n-1)/2} \cdot (q^n-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)$$

We proceed by induction: if n=1, is trivial.

Let assume $|GL(n-1,q)|=q^{(n-1)(n-2)/2} \cdot (q^{n-1}-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)$

Let $V=\mathbb{F}_q^n$. We know that $G$ is transitive about $V- \{0\}$. By Orbit-stabilizer Theorem, $|G|=|V- \{0\}| \cdot G_{b_1}$, where $b_1=(1,0,...,0)$ and $G_{b_1}$ is the stabilizer of $b_1$ . Notice that $|G_{b_1}|=|GL(n-1,q)| \cdot q^{n-1}$. Then

$$|G|=(q^n-1) \cdot q^{(n-1)(n-2)/2} \cdot (q^{n-1}-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q-1) \cdot q^{n-1}$$
$$|G|=q^{n(n-1)/2} \cdot (q^n-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)$$

I do not know if this helps. How is related, maybe it helps you.

Comment: @[leticia](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64596/leticia) Thanks for your insight. In this case are we supposed to put $q=2$? In that case, I believe we are undercounting as we are considering a matrix with determinant say $4$ as singular. Are we?

Comment: Yes. That's a problem... If det A = 2k, A is singular. So, we are counting the number of matrices A (0-1) with det A odd. If we get a relation between odd and even determinants, that will be great :)